# Preformat to currency and two decimal places in python using xlwt for excel

Tags: python, excel, xlwt

I have a column heading **Fee**. Using **xlwt** in **python**, I successfully generated the required excel.This column is always blank at the creation of Excel file.

Is it possible to have the **Fee** column preformatted to 'Currency' and 'two decimal places', so that when I write manually in the **Fee** column of the Excel file after downloading, **23** should change into **$23.00** ??

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I got it working like this:

`currency_style = xlwt.XFStyle()`

`currency_style.num_format_str = "[$$-409]#,##0.00;-[$$-409]#,##0.00"`

`sheet.write(row+2, col, val, style=currency_style)`

Comment: Can you please explain this, the values in `row`, `col` and `val`. The question was to auto-format values in the Fee column of the excel sheet when filling manually, so I was wondering if this code will be applied to the whole column of "Fee" without any looping. if there is a need for a for-loop how do I determine the number of rows that might be needed?